# Flurry ios sdk error in xcode 14+ version unable to build an app

Tags: ios, flurry, flurry-analytics

I have updated code 13 to 14.2 and after updating I am getting below error which I didn't get in xcode 13 etc . so I am unable to build it . please help what should I do? [image]

#flurry #ios

I want to build my app in xcode 14 + versions

Answer (score 0):

I am a member of Flurry's iOS SDK team.

I would suggest doing the following:

1. Remove Flurry from your podfile temporarily.
2. Run pod update
3. Add Flurry back to the podfile
4. Run pod update again

You can reach out to me directly at support@flurry.com if you need further assistance.